# What improvements can I make to my ordering a set of n numbers program?

Tags: javascript

I am just learning how to program in javascript and I made my first program that "does something". I didn't look for help for any part of the algorithm, just in some parts to find the name of a function I wanted to use. This algorithm seems to work, but it doesnt seem to finish when you have a big list of number, like 10 or more. What yo do you think of it? Is wholly ineficient?

```
var totNum = Number(prompt("How many numbers you want to compare"));
var unordNum = new Array(totNum);
var ordNum = new Array();
for( var i=1 ; i<= totNum; i++){
    unordNum[i] = Number(prompt("Write a new number","0"));
 }
while(ordNum.length < totNum){ // I will repeat this process until I order all numbers
    for(var i=1; i <=totNum; i++){ //choose a number, lets call it X
        if(!(ordNum.indexOf(unordNum[i]) >=0)){ //if it is already ordered, skip it
            var z = 0; 
            for(var j=1; j<=totNum; j++){ //I will compare X against all the others numbers, except
                if(!(ordNum.indexOf(unordNum[j]) >= 0)){ //the ones that are already ordered
                    if( unordNum[i] >= unordNum[j]){ //if X is bigger than a number,
                        z++; // add 1 to z
                        }
                    if(z==totNum-ordNum.length){ // this means X is bigger or equal than all the other numbers
                        ordNum.push(unordNum[i]); //so write X in the first empty space of the ordered list
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
document.write(ordNum + "<br>");
```

Comment: This sounds like a *great* opportunity to add the use of a debugger to your learning exercises.  When this page is in your browser, open your browser's debugging tools.  (Pressing F12, usually.)  What you want to find in those tools is the JavaScript code being executed on the page.  There you can place "breakpoints" in the code where execution will pause and you can begin to step through the code, line by line, as it executes.  You can observe the runtime behavior, the changing values of variables, etc.  With this, find where your logic differs from what you expect.

Comment: If this works, but you just want to know how to improve it, it would probably be better on _Code Review_.

Comment: @David thank you, but how do I see theh changing values of variables? And how do I insert a breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make use of `ordNum.indexOf(unordNum[j])` to find if a number is already sorted. This would lead to an infinite loop in case of duplicates. Secondly, you are not really sorting, you would push a number for the first comparison success.
Below is a somewhat similar logic for your sorting.

```
var totNum = Number(prompt("How many numbers you want to compare"));
var unordNum = new Array(totNum);
var ordNum = new Array();
for( var i=0 ; i< totNum; i++){
    unordNum[i] = Number(prompt("Write a new number","0"));
 }

    for(var i=0; i <totNum; i++){ 
        if(unordNum[i] == undefined) continue; //jump to the next unsorted number
        var smallest = unordNum[i];  //initialize smallest to be the first unsorted number
        var index = i;               //initialize marker index to be set as undefined at last for the number being moved to the sorted array
        for(var j=0; j<totNum; j++){ //Comparison loop to find the smallest
            if(unordNum[j] != undefined){
                smallest  = unordNum[j]<smallest ? unordNum[j] : smallest; //Swap if j th number is smaller
                index = smallest == unordNum[j] ? j : index; // update index if swapping done
            }
        }
        unordNum[index] = undefined;//mark the number moved
        ordNum.push(smallest);      // add smallest number to sorted array
        i=0;                        //set outer loop to start from 0 again
    }

document.write(ordNum + "<br>");
```

This would sort by copying the smallest number in the remaining array into a new array. Instead of using `ordNum.indexOf(unordNum[j])` as you did, I am marking the sorted element as `undefined`. Duplicates cannot be sorted in your case. This would leave the new sorted array smaller than the input array and hence an infinite loop. Another thing, why do you use 1 as the starting index? The default index starts from 0 in Javascript as well.

There are far better sorting algorithms but perhaps that is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen the "undefined" or " ? " or " : " symbols in javascript before, Your solution uses a lot of things I haven't seen yet. I have only seen loops like "for" and "while", conditions like "if", operators for comparing two elements, arrays, functions, and little else. And the function push which I had to google. I tried to do the best I could with the few tools I have seen so far. I will google what the "?" and ":" mean incode.

Comment: I used 1 because I forgot it starts at 0.

Comment: Question: is it allowed to use "if ( something) then something without the keys?  Here:

       if(unordNum[i] == undefined) continue;

I would have written "       if(unordNum[i] == undefined){ continue;
... }

Comment: Final question: could you have used any word instead of "undefined"? can you set any variable to be equal to any word?

Comment: Final question for real: I don't understand this line 

"smallest  = unordNum[j]<smallest ? unordNum[j] : smallest; //Swap if j th number is smaller"

Should it be

"  smallest  = (unordNum[j]<smallest ? unordNum[j] : smallest; //Swap if j th number is smaller) "

Like, you are assigning smallest according to a condition, if the condition is true, then "smallest" equals unordNum[j]. If the condition is false, "smallest" equals smallest

Comment: Well, the `? : ` operation is called a conditional operation used in many languages. Its a shortcut for `if...else`. `a = a > b ? b : a` - this would mean -  `if (a>b) { a = b; }else {a = a;}`.

Comment: If there is a single statement in the body of an `if,else,while,for,etc`, then you can escape the `{ }`. The braces are used to group a collection of statements.

Comment: `undefined` is a reserved word in Javascript. It means that a variable has no value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Answer (score -2):

Once you have numbers in array, you can use `array.sort()`

Comment: …to sort them alphabetically?

Comment: 'array.sort()' uses alphabetical short by default.

Comment: you can write custom function in array sort... its simpler than writing whole sort again.